# Scraping the tables from the .aspx web page with the multiple drop down optins

Tags: r

I would like to scrape the table’s data from this page http://agmarknet.gov.in/PriceTrends/SA_Month_PriMar.aspx.
Which ask for selecting the multiple options like "Commodity","state", "year" and "month". Then need to press submit button to get the table.

My attempt is to scrape the table associated with "Commodity"="Tomato","state"="Karnataka", "year"="2016" and "month"=ALL MONTH DATA. I am working with the following code in R

```
url<-"http://agmarknet.gov.in/PriceTrends/SA_Month_PriMar.aspx"
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgform <-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <-set_values(pgform,
                     "ctl00$cphBody$Commodit_list"= "Tomato",
                     "ctl00$cphBody$State_list" = "Karnataka",
                     "ctl00$cphBody$Yea_list"  = "2016",
                     "ctl00$cphBody$Mont_list" = "January"             
)
d <- submit_form(session=pgsession, form=filled_form)
y <- d %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%.[[2]] %>%
html_table(header=TRUE)
dim(y)
```

but I am getting a error message as:

```
Submitting with 'ctl00$ddlDistrict'
Warning message:
In request_POST(session, url = url, body = request$values, encode = 
request$encode,  :
Internal Server Error (HTTP 500).
```

I am not able to scrap the required table from the web page please help me to extract the table with the desired options from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method that uses `RSelenium` package to scrape data for all months of 2016.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "http://agmarknet.gov.in/PriceTrends/SA_Month_PriMar.aspx"

rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD$client

lst <- lapply(seq(2,13), function(x) {
  remDr$navigate(url)

  webElem_commodity <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#cphBody_Commodit_list")
  opts_commodity <- webElem_commodity$selectTag() # get all the associated tags
  commodity_num <- which(opts_commodity$text=="Tomato") # find the required option
  opts_commodity$elements[[commodity_num]]$clickElement() # select the required option

  Sys.sleep(10) # for state names to load

  webElem_state <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#cphBody_State_list")
  opts_state <- webElem_state$selectTag() 
  state_num <- which(opts_state$text=="Karnataka")
  opts_state$elements[[state_num]]$clickElement()

  Sys.sleep(10) # for years to load

  webElem_yr <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#cphBody_Yea_list")
  opts_yr <- webElem_yr$selectTag() 
  yr_num <- which(opts_yr$text=="2016")
  opts_yr$elements[[yr_num]]$clickElement()

  Sys.sleep(10) # for months to load

  webElem_month <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#cphBody_Mont_list")
  opts_month <- webElem_month$selectTag() 
  opts_month$elements[[x]]$clickElement() # select a different month in each lapply iteration

  Sys.sleep(10) # for submit button to become active

  webElem_submit <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#cphBody_But_Submit")
  webElem_submit$clickElement()

  page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()

  tdf <- read_html(page_source[[1]]) %>%     # read table 
    html_nodes("table") %>% .[[5]] %>%
    html_table(header=T,fill=T, trim=T) %>%
    head(-1) # remove the last row which contains average at the bottom of the scraped table
})

remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()
# lst is a list, with 12 elements. Each element corresponds to data for one month of 2016
```

Comment: Thank You Swapnil, But  I am getting following errors                                                    > webElem_commodity <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#cphBody_Commodit_list")

Selenium message:Unable to locate element: #cphBody_Commodit_list                                                                                                                                
Error: Summary: NoSuchElement
Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
   class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
  Further Details: run errorDetails method

Comment: Its working fin, I am able to scrape the tables now. Thank You very much Swapnil.